# Unable to convert Lowercase Letters from EBCDIC to ASCII

Tags: java, ascii, ebcdic

I have written the code to convert the data from EBCDIC to ASCII which is working fine for digits and Uppercase letters such as 1, 2, A, B, C. However, it not converting lowercase letters l and when are printing them in the logs it prints non readable characters. Below is the code snipped that we are using for conversion.

```
 public String ebcdicToAscii(String ebcdicValue) {
    String asciiBuffer = null;
    logger.debug("converting field value frm ebcdic to Ascii. ");
    try {

      byte[] ebcdicByteArr = ebcdicValue.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
      int textLen = ebcdicByteArr.length;
      AS400Text textConverter = new AS400Text(textLen);
      asciiBuffer = ((String) textConverter.toObject(ebcdicByteArr)).substring(0, textLen);
      System.out.println("value: "+asciiBuffer);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      logger.error("error while converting field value from ebcdic To Ascii:  " + e);
    }
    return asciiBuffer;
  }
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: The problem lies in the AS400Text code.

Comment: You're not converting EBCDIC to ASCII. Suppose `ebcdicValue` is `123`, then the ASCII bytes are `{0x31,0x32,0x33}` and the EBCDIC bytes are `{0xF1,0xF2,0xF3}`. Do you want to convert `{0xF1,0xF2,0xF3}` to `{0x31,0x32,0x33}`? It seems like `AS400Text` takes as input EBCDIC bytes array (such as `{0xF1,0xF2,0xF3}`) and returns a string of `123`.

Comment: I am trying to {0xF1,0xF2,0xF3} to {0x31,0x32,0x33}. Yes, AS400Text takes as input EBCDIC bytes array and returns String. What is the problem with AS400Text and how we can fix this?

Comment: > What is the problem with AS400Text and how we can fix this?

No one can know because no one has the code... You already know that the code works with digits and upper-case letters so the code for calling that seems fine. You also know that it does not work with lower case letters, so the place to inspect is possibly the conversion function.
Hm, but also suspicious: you use getBytes() with ISO_8859_1 encoding on data that is not valid ISO_8859_1 - if your Java runtime has support for a matching EBCDIC encoding then use that.

Comment: Thanks @SimonSobisch for you response, I will look around conversion function in more detail. Moreover, if a single value contains both upper and lowercase characters in that case as well it converts upper cases only. For example: It converts TesT into T^^T

Comment: Is this code java ???, if so it foes not make sense. A java String should be uni-code; it can not be EBCDIC unless you do something silly like like new String(ebcdicByteArray). We need to know how **ebcdicToAscii** is being called and how the parameter ebcdicValue is created.

Comment: Yes this is java code. We are reading records from ebcdic file using copybook information  and passing each column value in the above mentioned method for the conversion

Comment: It seems to me that you should extract the data as byte-array and pass this to a conversion function, because most likely you input "string" is not what you think it is.

Comment: When you read the file into a string, there is already a charset conversion and this conversion can cause data loss when not using the correct charset. On the other hand, when you specify the correct charset when reading the file into a string, e.g. `new FileReader(file, Charset.forName("IBM500"))`, your job is already done. There is no point in trying to convert a string to a string.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is only with lower letters then convert lowercase letters to uppercase:

```
String a = "{0xf1,0xf2,0xf3}";
    a = a.substring(1, a.length()-1); //delete first and last character {}
    String[] array = a.split(","); //separate with comma
    ArrayList<String> scripts = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
    {
          String b = array[i].substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + array[i].substring(1,2).toLowerCase() + array[i].substring(2).toUpperCase();
        scripts.add(b);
    }
System.out.println(scripts.toString());
```

Output is:

```
0xF1,0xF2,0xF3
```

Comment: How we can convert the EBCDIC data to upper case?

Comment: first you must to add EBCDIC text to array. Then if they are separated with comma use subString to get every EBCDIC separated. Then you use for loop to convert from lowercase to uppercase and save it in array. Then simple use array or convert it to string. :)